# Convert a Gdiplus::Bitmap* object into HBITMAP

Tags: visual-c++, bitmap, mfc

How do i convert a Gdiplus::Bitmap* object into HBITMAP? I am using:

```
Gdiplus::Color colorW(255, 255, 255, 255);  
Status status =img->GetHBITMAP(colorW, &hBmp);
```

But when i debug, it note that hBmp is unused!
Help me please!

Comment: where do you declare `hBmp` ?

Comment: i declare hBmp in above them: HBITMAP hBmp = NULL;

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: It hasn't error but i want to display this image on a List, it notes that expression cannot be evaluated, i get img by using:    Gdiplus::Bitmap* img = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(pStream); and now i want to convert this  img into a HBITMAP to add on Picture Control to test.

Comment: That looks okay, apart from I can't see any status checking code. What value is status when you run it?

Comment: status is Ok but hBmp is unused and expression can not be evaluated.

Comment: Did you GdiplusStartup before and GdiplusShutdown after?